# Do i need to add host name to DNS server

Tags: iis, dns, iis-7.5

I am hosting and application in IIS. the application is a INTRANET APPLICATION.
Already the server has 2 application hosted in it with host names

> site1.k.com and  site2.k.com

k.com is my domain name.
I have give host name for my site as

> site3.k.com

Do i have to make DNS entry for this.

Comment: No, you don't need a DNS entry if you want clients to use the IP number to access the site. Otherwise, yes, you do.

Comment: Not all sites use specific IP addresses.  @JoachimIsaksson's advice won't work if the site is configured to use virtual hosts that share an IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a wildcard dns entry such that `<anything>.k.com` goes to your server, then you don't need a specific DNS entry for `site3.k.com`, but it might make things easier down the road if you have it.

Of course, if you don't have the wildcard set up, and you need to have the url for `site3.k.com` work, then yeah, it'd be required.

Now, you mention that this is intranet ... if you have a windows server configured to broadcast that it's name is `site3` via WINS service, then you might get away with not having the DNS entry, but this behavior is not reliable, because WINS may or may not route to remote sites, depending on WAN and/or VPN configurations, and will generally be a pain in the ass for support.

Comment: canI check the DNS entry for in server. if so how can i do that

Comment: you can use `nslookup site3.k.com` on windows, or `dig site3.k.com` on linux to see if site3 is published.  To check specific servers on specific configurations you need to talk to your IT department.